# How to install LibreOffice 3.3.1?

Tags: 10.04, ppa, libreoffice, installation

How do I install the new version of LibreOffice (3.3.1) in Ubuntu 10.04? I have installed the PPA for LibreOffice but no updates show up.

Comment: Did you check and see the PPA page if they have builds for 10.04?

Comment: It's still building, you can check on https://launchpad.net/builders

Comment: actually I have the same issue. I have the libreoffice ppa however I did not get any update for libreoffice 3.3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using [this one](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa), 3.3.1 is currently building for Maverick (10.10). I assume lucid is still to follow.

If you really can't wait, then you can always go and build it yourself by grabbing the [source code](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/).

Comment: I'll wait :) I think in a few weeks will be ready.

Comment: OK updated today !!! once again thnx you all!!

Answer (score 3):

Libreoffice also provides DEB packages (see [downdload page](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/)). These are usually built at release time and work fine with Ubuntu.

Then to install you (see [official instructions](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Installing_LibreOffice_on_Linux) for more details)

1. remove the old version with `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*`
2. unpack the downloaded file (the "easiest" way is: right-click->Extract here)
3. `cd` into the unpacked directory and run `sudo dpkg -i DEBS/*.deb` and `sudo dpkg -i DEBS/desktop-integration/*.deb`

That's how you always get the latest release. Though, you manually have to deinstall/install at every version.